# Mac OS X Notification with same Vendor ID and different Product IDs

Tags: macos, cocoa, usb, foundation, iokit

Tried this solution from a stackfow link:

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef  matchingDict = IOServiceMatching ( kIOUSBDeviceClassName );
if ( matchingDict )
{
    UInt32        usbVendor = k_MyVendorID;
    CFNumberRef   refVendorId = CFNumberCreate ( kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberIntType, &usbVendor );
    CFDictionarySetValue ( matchingDict, CFSTR ( kUSBVendorID ), refVendorId );
    CFRelease ( refVendorID );
    CFDictionarySetValue ( matchingDict, CFSTR ( kUSBProductID ), CFSTR ( "*" ) );   // This is a wildcard, so we find any device.
}
```

On Add new device seem to work:

```
kr = IOServiceAddMatchingNotification(gNotifyPort,kIOMatchedNotification, matchingDict, RawDeviceAdded, NULL, &gRawAddedIter);
```

With these it either crashes or the list does not get updated, with remove device does seem to work.
//Notification of termination:

```
kr = IOServiceAddMatchingNotification(gNotifyPort, kIOTerminatedNotification, matchingDict, RawDeviceRemoved, NULL, &gRawRemovedIter);
```

//Notification of termination:

```
kr = IOServiceAddMatchingNotification(gNotifyPort, kIOTerminatedNotification, matchingDict, NonRawDeviceRemoved, NULL, &gRawRemovedIter);
```

What is the best method to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to re-use the same `matchingDict` for both calls to `IOServiceAddMatchingNotification`? The `IOServiceAddMatchingNotification` and similar functions all release the incoming matching dictionary, so if you want to use it twice, you must `CFRetain(matchingDict);` once before you start using it.

(Build -> Analyze should in theory catch this error for you.)